# awk on a single line for a particular substring and then merge

Tags: unix, awk

I have several XML files with the whole content in one line. I want to merge the part between `<p1>`and `</p1>` tags of different files in one file. Is it possible to do so using awk?

Comment: Try this: `grep -o '<p1>.*</p1>' inputfile* > outputfile`

Comment: Yes, it's most probably possible although you would need to show us an example to make your question more clear. It would also be good to see what you've tried so far. Bear in mind that AWK is not designed to process XML, so it is likely that any solution will break when the input changes.

Comment: This is rather off-topic on SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
`cat * | awk -F"<p1>" '{print $2;}' | awk -F"</p1>" '{print $1;}' > output.txt`

Comment: That approach could be implemented as: `awk -v RS="(<p1>|</p1>)" 'FNR%2==0{print $1}' *.xml`

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to see what must be done against small errors in the input file. The `grep -o` solution will fail for input with 2 paragraphs on 1 line, and what do you want when `<p1>` is found and `</p1>` is missing?
Try `awk` (comment of @James) or `sed`:

```
sed 's#</p1>#\n#g' xmlfiles | sed -n '/<p1>/ s#.*<p1>##p'
```